# Batch file needed to query a specific location

Tags: batch, powershell, windows-server-2008, batch-file

I am not a coder and would appreciate any assistance.

I need a batch file which will query a NAS location and produce an output of the upper level directories (and maybe the second level down). The file structure is as follows:

```
\\NAS-ip\home\user1
\\NAS-ip\home\user2
\\NAS-ip\home\user3
\\NAS-ip\home\user4
        ︙
\\NAS-ip\home\user99
```

The batch output would need to be:

```
\\NAS-ip\home\user1,\\NAS-ip\home\user2,\\NAS-ip\home\user3,\\NAS-ip\home\user4 … etc.
```

Comment: What OS will you be running this on? Might be easier to do in PowerShell than batch, if running Vista or above.

Comment: A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?&q=directory%20recurse%20n%20levels) seems to indicate it's doable via batch or PowerShell. It's not very difficult, but not nearly as simple as one might like it to be.

Comment: Running Windows 2008 x64. I have attempted DOSing it with no luck. And not familiar with Powershell

Comment: If you're running 7/2008 or higher, and planning on doing system administration or power user tweaks on a regular basis, I strongly suggest you get familiar with PowerShell. It's effectively the new CMD.

Comment: So, you want the output to be a single line that is over 2000 characters long (i.e., wide)?

Comment: Yes, with a comma after each user directory. I am trying to figure it out in Powershell but I am new to it.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell:

Human-readable:

```powershell
(@{Path = '\\NAS-ip\home' ; Levels = '2'} |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-ChildItem -Path ($_.Path + ((@('\*') * $_.Levels) -join '')) |
            Where-Object {$_.PsIsContainer} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
    }) -join ','
```

One-liner:

```powershell
(@{Path = '\\NAS-ip\home' ; Levels = '2'} | ForEach-Object {Get-ChildItem -Path ($_.Path + ((@('\*') * $_.Levels) -join '')) | Where-Object {$_.PsIsContainer} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName}) -join ','
```

Compact:

```powershell
(@{Path = '\\NAS-ip\home' ; Levels = '2'} | % {gci ($_.Path + ((@('\*') * $_.Levels) -join '')) | ? {$_.PsIsContainer} | select -Exp FullName}) -join ','
```

Change `Path` and `Levels` as you see fit. And I advise you to change separator from `,` to something like `|`, because comma is allowed in filenames and could lead to ambiguity. To change separator, edit last `-join ','` to `-join '|'`.

Bonus: to get list of subdirs in multiple initial paths, separate hashtables at the beginning with comma:

```powershell
(@{Path = '\\NAS-ip\home' ; Levels = '2'}, @{Path = '\\NAS2-ip\somedir' ; Levels = '3'} |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-ChildItem -Path ($_.Path + ((@('\*') * $_.Levels) -join '')) |
            Where-Object {$_.PsIsContainer} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
    }) -join ','
```